# How to set up optional parameters to check for the parameter being provided?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a route which I would like to satisfy 3 conditions. These conditions are:

Report 1 = ClientID, SupplierID, ReviewPeriodID

Report 2 = ClientID, SupplierID

Report 3 = ClientID, ReviewPeriodID.

The route I use at the moment is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "SupplierReportBoth",
             url: "{client}/Reports/SupplierReportSelection/{ClientID}/{SupplierID}/{ReviewPeriodID}",
             defaults: new { client = "APL", controller = "Reports", action = "SupplierReportSelection", ClientID = UrlParameter.Optional, SupplierID = "", ReviewPeriodID = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
```

This satisfies 2 of the 3 report types. It satisfies report type 1 and report type 2. However, when I get to the third report type the routing fails and it moves onto a more generic route and it doesn't look very good.

The problem lies with the positioning of the parameters in the route. Because SupplierID is first but I'm using ReviewPeriodID, it will not recognise which ID is being passed through.

Is there a way to fix this?

Sorry, it's really difficult to explain

Answer (score 0):

Your routing parameters for 2 and 3 are the same ie. int/int. The router cannot distinguish between them. You could just have one controller action and use the query string parameters to decide which report to return.